# Array from VBA into Python win32com

Tags: python, filter, pivot, olap, cube

How can I translate this VBA code into python code?

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[dim_POS_reported_months].[Reported Month].[Reported Month]"). _
        VisibleItemsList = Array("[dim_POS_reported_months].[Reported Month].&[APR'22]" _
        )
```

It should basically change a filter on the pivot table sourced from OLAP cube hence use of the Array. Python does not recognize "Array"

Comment: What Python library are you using to interact with Excel?

Comment: I'm using win32com

Answer (score 0):

OK, I almost figured it out. Here's the code that works:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[dim_POS_reported_months].[Reported Month].[Reported Month]").CurrentPageName = "[dim_POS_reported_months].[Reported Month].&[APR'22]"
```

However when I use another Excel instance at the same time when running the script I get an error most likely due to "CurrentPageName" which is incorrectly recognized. Is there anyway I can replace "CurrentPageName" so that I can work
with Excel while running the script?

I tried:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[dim_POS_reported_months].[Reported Month].[Reported Month]").PivotFilters.Add2(15,None,"[dim_POS_reported_months].[Reported Month].&[APR'22]")
```

but doesn't work. I get an error:

```
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in Add2
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```